# Global menu in nautilus disappeared

Tags: unity, nautilus

After restart computer global menu in nautilus disappeared.
Ubuntu 14.04
[image]

Comment: Type `sudo apt-get install indicator-appmenu` in Terminal. I think it will solve the issue.

Comment: I've already this package

Comment: Type `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. If you do have that too installed, remove it and re-install it. Remove that `indicator-appmenu` too and re-install it. Then, reboot your system.

Comment: What Nautilus version is this? It looks like you addded the gnome3 PPA.

Comment: Nautilus package is 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.4. I tried to reinstall ubuntu-desktop and nothing...

Comment: If no one else comes up with anything, you can always install the [Nemo File Manager](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo).  It does the same as Nautilus and looks very similar, but just has a few more advanced features.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue since a couple of weeks and thought it would go away automatically (some problems do ...) So I didn't remember what caused the changes. Thank you @xangua, the hint about gnome3 helped. I found the repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging in my apt sources which I added because I had issues with the nautilus dropbox client

To get the default nautilus menu back (top menu + context menu), I had to force version 3.10 instead of version 3.12 (apparently installed with the gnome3 ppa):

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus nautilus-sendto nautilus-share ubuntu-desktop indicator-appmenu
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus=1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11 nautilus-data=1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11
sudo apt-get install nautilus-sendto nautilus-share ubuntu-desktop indicator-appmenu
nautilus -q
```

output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep nautilus | awk '{print $2 "------" $3}'`

```
libnautilus-extension1a------1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11
nautilus------1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11
nautilus-data------1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11
nautilus-dropbox------1.6.1-1
nautilus-sendto------3.6.1-2ubuntu1
nautilus-sendto-empathy------3.8.6-0ubuntu9.2
nautilus-share------0.7.3-1ubuntu5
seahorse-nautilus------3.8.0-0ubuntu2
```

I haven't restarted yet, so I don't know if the dropbox support is back working. But having the menu's back is more important for me anyway.

Tim